# force:recordData is returning parentId on case as null

Tags: lightning-aura-components

force:recordData is returning parentId on case as null even though valid ParentId exists on the case record.

code:

cmp:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
      layoutType="FULL"
      fields="Id,ParentId"
      targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
      />
```

Controller file:

```
onInit: function (component, event) {

    console.log("oninituccess" + component.get("v.simpleRecord").ParentId);

    },
  handleRecordUpdated: function (component, event, helper) {

    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if (eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
      helper.onInit(component, event);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that "recordData" doesn't pull the data before your onInit function runs.  You need to allow the form to fully load before looking at the record data.

For more info on using force:recordData:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_data_service/lightning_data_service_manipulate_records

Try using on-render instead of on-init:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_render_handler.htm

Comment: Thanks Paul,I have code to check whether record is loaded. I cannot noticed that other fields like Id and OwnerId can be pulled but not ParentId.                                                   
    var eventParams = event.getParams();
    if (eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
      // record is loaded (render other component which needs record data value)
      console.log("Record is loaded successfully.");
      helper.onInit(component, event);
    }

Comment: That is strange and doesn't appear to be acting as expected.  Try removing layoutType="FULL" - perhaps that is overriding the fields (it shouldn't, but perhaps, something to try).

Answer (score 0):

The control visibility was set to false for ParentId on flexipage. Non issue. Thanks Paul for your help.